# Having Get single and Get all methods on a ApiController

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing an API using close to the latest bits from the aspnetwebstack Codeplex project (4592e2f63c55 from 2012-05-09 if anyone is interested).

I have the following route:

```
context.Routes.MapHttpRoute("SiteSpecific", "Api/{controller}/{customerId}/{siteToken}/{id}",
                new { id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

And what I'm currently trying to do is implement get single and a get all in an `ApiController`. The Get all method, for testing is the following:

```
public IEnumerable<EditChatResponse> Get(string customerId, string siteToken)
{
    return new []{new EditChatResponse{Template = "Get All"}, };
}
```

And the get single is currently following:

```
public EditChatResponse Get(string customerId, string siteToken, string id)
{
    return new EditChatResponse {Template = "Get Single"};
}
```

However, routing is always choosing the Get single method:

```
$ curl -i -H "Accept: applicaiton/json" http://localhost/api/chatresponse/a/b
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 14 May 2012 18:06:26 GMT
Content-Length: 66

{"Id":0,"Template":"Get Single","Inherited":false,"Enabled":false}


$ curl -i -H "Accept: applicaiton/json" http://localhost/api/chatresponse/a/b/c
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 14 May 2012 18:06:28 GMT
Content-Length: 66

{"Id":0,"Template":"Get Single","Inherited":false,"Enabled":false}
```

I've tried renaming the Get all method to `GetAll`, as I've seen in some examples, decorating it with `[HttpGet]`, but it still chooses the single method.

Am I completely missing something, or do I need to go about this a different way (most of the examples I see look to be related to the beta bits, and not a recent version from CodePlex)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this for the default id parameter:

> new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }